# Реализовать методы итератора вручную в классе

Tags: java, ооп, итераторы

Само задание:

1. Реализовать класс-контейнер, который итеририуется по массиву строк с возможностью добавления, удаления и изменения елементов.
2. В контейнере реализовать следующие методы:

- String toString()
- void add(String string)
- void clear()
- boolean remove(String string)
- Object[] toArray()
- int size()
- boolean contains(String string)
- boolean containsAll(Container container)
- **public Iterator iterator()** - возвращает итератор, соответственно `Interface Iterable`

3. В классе итератора реализовать соответственно `Interface Iterator` следующие методы:

- **public boolean hasNext()**
- **public String next()**
- **public void remove()**

4. **Продемонстрировать работу итератора при помощи циклов *while* и *for each***

---

Как реализовать метод `remove()`?

Код:

```java
package Laba05;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        //String text = sc.nextLine();
        String text = "This text is for lab05";
        
        String[] string_array = text.split(" ");

        Container container = new Container(string_array);

        // task 1.1
        System.out.println(container.toString());
        
        // task 1.2
        container.add("text");
        System.out.println(container.toString());

        // task 1.3
        container.clear();
        System.out.println("New string: " + container.toString());

        //-------------------------------------------------------
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            container.add("Text" + i);
        //-------------------------------------------------------        

        // task 1.4
        System.out.println(container.remove("Text2"));

        // task 1.5
        Object[] t4 = container.toArray();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(t4));

        // task 1.6
        System.out.println("Size: " + container.size());

        // task 1.7
        System.out.println(container.contains("Text2"));

        // task 1.8 
        Container cnt;
        System.out.println(container.containsAll(cnt));
        
    }
}

public class Container {

    public class IteratorClass implements Iterator<String> {
        public boolean hasNext() {
            
        }

        public String next() {

        }

        public void remove() {

        }
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String[] str_arr;

    public Container(String[] string_array) {
        str_arr = string_array;

        for (int i = 0; i < string_array.length; i++)
            sb.append(string_array[i]).append(" ");
    }

    public String toString() {
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public void add(String string) {
        sb.append(string).append(" ");
    }

    public void clear() {
        sb.delete(0, sb.length());
    }

    boolean remove(String string) {
        //return sb.toString().contains(string) ? sb.toString().replace(string, "") : false;
        return sb.toString().contains(string) ? true : false;
    }

    String[] toArray() {
        String[] outputArray = sb.toString().split(" ");

        return outputArray;
    }

    int size() {
        return sb.length();
    }

    boolean contains(String string) {
        return sb.toString().contains(string) ? true : false;
    }

    boolean containsAll(Container container) {
        boolean isTrue = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < container.toString().length(); i++) {
            if (!container.toString().contains(container.toArray()[i]))
                isTrue = true;
            else 
                isTrue = false;
        }

        return isTrue;
    }

    
    public Iterator<String> iterator() {
        return new IteratorClass();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Зная текущий индекс элемента у итератора левую и правую часть от элемента в текущем массиве копируешь в новый массив.

Также можно посмотреть как реализовано в стандартной библиотеке java.
`java.util.ArrayList.Itr#remove`

```
public void remove() {
            if (lastRet < 0)
                throw new IllegalStateException();
            checkForComodification();

            try {
                ArrayList.this.remove(lastRet);
                cursor = lastRet;
                lastRet = -1;
                expectedModCount = modCount;
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
                throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Вариант хороший, однако не могу принять как решение, поскольку здесь не идет речи о применении ArrayList